# only splash screen display when i add drawer navigation in react native expo CLI

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation-drawer

my android application work well but when i add drawer navigation library `import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';`  in my app only splash screen display, No error are display in cmd. I wait a lot but  not open the screen.
[image]

Comment: Please update the full code, so we can help you